# How to split the image in pdfMake and insert to multiple pages using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html2canvas, pdfmake

At first I thought it is working fine but after a couple of testing, the data became large enough that it won't fit to one page. I researched some questions but it didn't help me enough

so here's my code

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById(id)).then(function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var height = canvas.height;
            canvas.remove();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,


                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(id+".pdf", function() {
                $scope.balanceSheet = false;
                $scope.mainPage = true;
            });

        });
```

I have at least 90 rows here but the image was cut at 46
[image]

any idea how to split it? I've already tried raising the height but it just fit the whole 90 rows into one page.

The page break showed because I added

```
 content: [{
    image: data,
    width: 500,
    pageBreak: 'after',
   }]
```

Here's a sample how to split it [here](https://gist.github.com/Balkoth/d79a520ca2a3377c15e902ec68790aff)
but I can't read it because it is not angular :(
can anyone explain it or convert it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Export HTML to PDF (multiple pages) using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308280/how-to-export-html-to-pdf-multiple-pages-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can split images in different pages automatically in pdfmake.

But you may split the canvas beforehand using the method [`drawImage`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp). Check the parameters of the function and you can split an image vertically on every point you'd like, and then set those two subimages in different pages

Comment: here's a sample https://gist.github.com/Balkoth/d79a520ca2a3377c15e902ec68790aff but it is not in angular and can't read it :(

Comment: @Mark I don't know angular but I think here is irrelevant. pdfMake just needs javascript.

Comment: I just made one with AngularJS. it is just that I can't translate it to the correct syntax for angular since I don't know javascript

Comment: @Mark, really, read the documentation of of drawImage, and then just apply that to your `canvas`